# Why won't this simple c programme compile?

Tags: c, eclipse

I have just started studying C for the first time and I am encountering many problems.
When I write a HelloWorld application using printf everything works a treat, however when I include scanf functions or even a char variable nothing seems to want to work. I understand this may be a silly question, but I would really appreciate any help that's available.

Some of the Errors I have had while trying to compile include:

In function ‘main’:
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Now, when I try to compile I get no error messages, just nothing is produced or executable at the end. Please help, many thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
   int Numb;

   printf( "Hello world\n");
   printf( "I'm Kallum/n");
   printf( "Choose a Number Between one and ten: ");
   scanf( "%d", &Numb);
   printf("This is your Number %d!", Numb);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It compiles find from the command line. My best guess is that you did something wrong setting up your eclipse project.

Comment: that is a warning, not an error.

Comment: You say you get no error messages, which is to be expected since the program in the question looks fine. We can't help with the error message you mentioned, since we can't see the code that caused it. My guess is that your program *is* compiling and producing an executable; you're just not seeing it. The problem is knowing how to use Eclipse (which I don't, so I can't help with that).

Comment: @migas: Yes, gcc issues a warning, but it's for a constraint violation; IMHO it *should* be a fatal error. (And with `-pedantic-errors`, it is.) But the code now in the question doesn't produce that message anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I found that when I clicked on the application and entered a number, everything that I printed appeared including the number I typed in!

Comment: Just ran it through the command line and it worked absolutely fine, gues it was just the way I set up eclipse, thanks for the help!

Comment: unrelated: `printf( "I'm Kallum/n");` isn't going to end with a newline like `printf( "Hello world\n");`. In short, `/n` is not `\n`. Second, you may want to add a `\n` to the end of your last `printf`, particularly if you're interactively debugging and expect to see console output after that `printf` call.

Comment: Use `\n`  at end of *every* `printf` format string. Or learn how to use `fflush`; and usually variables are in lowercase, so `kalum` not `Kalum`. Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). And learn how to compile on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The above code will compile and give you the expected output .I am not sure which 
compiler are you using try with GCC .

Small point  please follow some book to understand, before you write the code .